# LINQ- Get the Index of an element in a collection (grouping by multiple/conditional fields)

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am trying to solve the following LINQ problem: to get the correct index of an element in a collection of objects (if element is found) or return the next index that should be assigned to it (if not found).

My scenario is a bit more complex than that one: https://coderwall.com/p/iqrkuq/get-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-collection-via-linq since the class I am dealing with is as follows:

```
public class PersonIdentifier
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BirthDateDate { get; set; }

        public string PersonID { get; set; } //this field is a concatenation of FirstName + LastName  + **the index associated to the birthdate**.
    }
```

I can group by or split using any of the 3 first properties. Each of them depends on a boolean condition:

```
bool SplitByFirstName; //value can be true or false
bool SplitByLastName;  //value can be true or false
bool SplitByBirthDate = true; //value is always true because the **purpose of the method is to get the correct index associated to a given birth date.**
```

My collection is a list as follows:

```
private static IList<PersonIdentifier> PersonList =
    new List<PersonIdentifier>()
    {
        new PersonIdentifier() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "DOE", BirthDateDate = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), PersonID = "JohnDOE1" },
    };
```

Actually, I tried this:

```
private static int GenerateIndice(bool splitByFirstName, bool splitByLastName, string relatedFirstName, string relatedLastName, DateTime? birthDate)
{
    if (PersonList.Any())
    {

        if (splitByFirstName == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(relatedFirstName))
        {
            //TODO
        }

        if (splitByLastName == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(relatedLastName))
        {
           //TODO
        }

        //remember that SplitbyBirthDate is always true.
        if (birthDate != null)
        {

            var results = PersonList.GroupBy(p => new { p.BirthDate });

            int indice = results.Where(ex => ex.Key.BirthDate.HasValue && ex.Key.BirthDate == birthDate).Count();

            if (indice == 0)
            {
                return results.Distinct().Count() + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return results.Select((ex, i) => new
                {
                    Item = ex,
                    Position = i
                }).Where(m => m.Item.Key.BirthDate == birthDate).First().Position + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This seems to always return the correct index associated to the birthdate. However, the code should work for any combination of the boolean values:

[combination of the 3 boolean possible values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkjro.png)

When adding another John DOE (with a different birth date), the index returned should be 2 in this scenario as we already have 1 John DOE in the list.

I need your help please. Thanks guys and sorry for the english as i am a french speaker.

Some scenarios to explain the usage of the bools
[usage of the bools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut3tw.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what these splitByFirst/Last/Birthdate bools are trying to achieve.  I recommend looking into the Select Overload which will project an index along with your the person object in your list. [Select Overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__)

[edit]

You're not really finding the "index" of an item in you collection, you're finding the count of a items with similar properties.  At some point you need to decide which properties you'd like to be in common.  you can do this with a series of lambda functions, or by crafting a concatenated (not split) string, but at some point you need to make the determination of what properties you want to be in common.

this is what i came up with.

```
void Main()
{
    var people = new List<Person>();

    var personOne = new Person{ FirstName = "jeff", LastName = "my name is", BirthDate = DateTime.Today};
    people.Add(personOne);
    Console.WriteLine(AddPerson(personOne, people, GroupCriteria.Birthday));
    Console.WriteLine(AddPerson(personOne, people, GroupCriteria.BirthdayFirstName));
    Console.WriteLine(AddPerson(personOne, people, GroupCriteria.BirthdayFirstNameLastName));
    Console.WriteLine(AddPerson(personOne, people, GroupCriteria.BirthdayLastName));

    var personTwo = new Person{ FirstName = "not jeff", LastName = "my name is", BirthDate = DateTime.Today};
    people.Add(personTwo);
    Console.WriteLine(AddPerson(personTwo, people, GroupCriteria.Birthday));
    Console.WriteLine(AddPerson(personTwo, people, GroupCriteria.BirthdayFirstName));
    Console.WriteLine(AddPerson(personTwo, people, GroupCriteria.BirthdayFirstNameLastName));
    Console.WriteLine(AddPerson(personTwo, people, GroupCriteria.BirthdayLastName));
}

int AddPerson(Person newPerson, List<Person> people, GroupCriteria crit)
{
    Func<Person, bool> countFunc = p => p.BirthDate == newPerson.BirthDate; ;

    switch(crit)
    {
        case GroupCriteria.Birthday:
            countFunc = p => p.BirthDate == newPerson.BirthDate;
            break;
        case GroupCriteria.BirthdayFirstName:
            countFunc = p => p.BirthDate == newPerson.BirthDate && p.FirstName == newPerson.FirstName;
            break;
        case GroupCriteria.BirthdayLastName:
            countFunc = p => p.BirthDate == newPerson.BirthDate && p.LastName == newPerson.LastName;
            break;
        case GroupCriteria.BirthdayFirstNameLastName:
            countFunc = p => p.BirthDate == newPerson.BirthDate && p.FirstName == newPerson.FirstName && p.LastName == newPerson.LastName;
            break;
    }

    var index = people.Count(countFunc);

    if(index == 0)
        return people.Count + 1;

    return index;
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDate {get;set;}
}

public enum GroupCriteria
{
    Birthday,
    BirthdayFirstName,
    BirthdayLastName,
    BirthdayFirstNameLastName
}
```

It seems like a silly exercise. that doesn't have a ton to do with linq.  Would love to see someone smarter than me comes up with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very interesting. I will try it.

Comment: To answer your question, the bools are used to filter. I mean if splitByFirstName is true that means I should check in the list if the FirstName (parameter) exists and get the index accordingly. if splitByLastName is true that means I should check in the list if the LastName (passed in parameter) exists already and get the index accordingly.

Comment: I just added a link at the end of my question (usage of the bools) to explain it more.